# How can I do that? Classes call functions from each others (include-forward anomaly)

Tags: pointers, include

I would like to call the Foo() function from class A through the other class's pointer
(I cannot include the other class's header, cause I do that on the other class, so it would result a ,,contains itself'' error)

```
//a.h


class X; // here I can't include "x.h", so forward declaration, but that results incomplete type

class A
{
 X* ptr;

 void Example()
 {
  X->Foo();    // it can't be use, casue ,,incomplete type is not allowed''
 }


 void Print();
}
```

---

```
//x.h
#include "a.h"

class X
{
 A* ptrarray[];

 void Foo();

 void List()
 {
  for (i...)
    ptrarray[i]->Print();  // ok, works fine
 }
}
```

How can I get around this problem, can you give me any advice?

Comment: Use header guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work... Or please show me the proper use of that in this example. Thanks

Comment: Split your files to a .h and .cpp and then put the implementation in the cpp file. That way, you only need to forward declare classes and not include the headers in the .h files.

Comment: I completely do that way in my project
(in the example code I only wrote the definitions into the classes declaration because for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: Wowwwwwww, it finally works!! The right uses of the include guards was the key

Answer (score 0):

Define Foo() and void List() in another file. And pass X and A as first parameter to them.
When you will define them there you will not get this error of incomplete type, because compiler would have got their definition early.
so thrid file will look like

```
// wrapper.h
include <a.h>
include <x.h>

void Foo(X *objX, ....);
void List(A *objA, ....);

//wrapper.cpp
void Foo(X *objX, ....)
{
  objX->Foo(....);  
}

void List(A *objA, ....)
{
  objA->List()l
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Ye, I thought about this solution, but in my project it is very important, that the named functions (Foo, List etc) to be the part of theese classes (because of the encapsulation and other OO principles)

Answer (score 0):

What mistake you are doing is you are defining class member functions in the .h file itself.
So please declare them outside class declaration in the corrosponding a.cpp and x.cpp. And add   a.h and x.h in both a.cpp and x.cpp. Well if you want them to be inline, you may add inline to them while defining outside of class declaration

Comment: In my project the definitions are in the .cpp files, and the declarations in the .h file (in this example code I only wrote the definitions into the classes declaration because for the sake of simplicity, to show what is purpose of the funcs and what are they using)